# How do you query by Date and Date Range in Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

This would be the equivalent of this SQL statement?

```
Select * from example WHERE date = '2011-09-21'
```

The record is stored with a MongoDate field.

I would also like to know the syntax of the between query.

Comment: Have you looked for the manual information? (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php)

Answer (score 8):

> This would be the equivalent of this SQL statement?
>
> Select * from example WHERE date = '2011-09-21'

```
db.example.find({date: dateobject});
```

In the case of MongoDB + PHP, you'll want to use the `[MongoDate][2]` class to represent those dates. Other language drivers typically just use the language date construct.

> I would also like to know the syntax of the between query.

MongoDB does not have a `between` clause.

To use "Greater than" you will need to use one of the query operators. See [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%3C,%3C=,%3E,%3E=) for details. Simple example:

```
db.example.find({ date: { $gt: lowdate, $lt: highdate } });
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the exact syntax for the PHP driver.  I have tried `code`$startDate = new MongoDate(strtotime($post['startdate'])); $query = array( "date" => $startDate );
$cursor = $collection->find( $query );`code` and this did not work

Comment: `$query = array('$gt' => $startDate, '$lt' => $endDate);` should do the trick.